How do you initially publish a package to an Azure artifact repository using rushjs?
I have had to migrate some of our code to a new monorepo, and after looking at the options, we've decided to go with Rush. I've set the monorepo up, and I believe I have configured it correctly. rush update and rush build work as expected, so I have been trying to work with rush publish to do a test publish to our artifact repository.
I have added our repository to the .npmrc-publish file
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/OURCOMPANY/OURPROJECT/_packaging/OURREPOSITORY/npm/registry/:\_authToken=${AZURE_ARTIFACTS_CI_AUTH_TOKEN}
always-auth=true

(I have also added the AZURE_ARTIFACTS_CI_AUTH_TOKEN to my .env file)
I run the change: rush change
Found configuration in C:\myproject\rush.json


Rush Multi-Project Build Tool 5.130.1 - https://rushjs.io
Node.js version is 20.15.1 (LTS)

Found configuration in C:\myproject\rush.json

Starting "rush change"

The target branch is origin/main
Checking for updates to origin/main...

@myscope/my-project
? Describe changes, or ENTER if no changes: chore: initial publish test
? Select the type of change: patch - for changes that do not affect compatibility, e.g. fixing a bug
Created file: C:\myproject\common\changes\@myscope\my-project\ci-testing-publishing_2024-07-19-01-36.json

This created the CHANGELOG.json, which all looks correct.
I then run rush publish --apply --publish
Found configuration in C:\onbord\MYCOMPANY\rush.json


Rush Multi-Project Build Tool 5.130.1 - https://rushjs.io
Node.js version is 20.15.1 (LTS)

Found configuration in C:\onbord\MYCOMPANY\rush.json

Starting "rush publish"

Validating package manager shrinkwrap file.

Transforming C:\onbord\MYCOMPANY\common\config\rush\.npmrc-publish
  --> "C:\onbord\MYCOMPANY\common\temp\publish-home\.npmrc"
Finding changes in: C:\onbord\MYCOMPANY\common\changes

* DRYRUN: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe checkout -b publish-1721370725310

* APPLYING: patch update for @MYCOMPANY/my-project to 0.1.4
 - [patch] Update to test publish, again!

* APPLYING: Changelog update for "@MYCOMPANY/my-project@0.1.4".

* DELETING: 1 change file(s).
 - C:/onbord/MYCOMPANY/common/changes/@MYCOMPANY/my-project/ci-testing-publishing_2024-07-19-06-32.json

* DRYRUN: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe add :/*

* DRYRUN: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe commit -m Bump versions [skip ci]

* DRYRUN: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe push origin HEAD:publish-1721370725310 --follow-tags --verbose
Package @MYCOMPANY/my-project does not exist in the registry.

* EXECUTING: C:\MYCOMPANY\common\temp\pnpm-local\node_modules\.bin\pnpm publish --no-git-checks
npm notice
npm notice   @MYCOMPANY/my-project@0.1.4
npm notice Tarball Contents
npm notice 397B .rush/temp/chunked-rush-logs/my-project.build.chunks.jsonl
npm notice 743B .rush/temp/package-deps_build.json
npm notice 16.2kB .rush/temp/shrinkwrap-deps.json
npm notice 1.1kB CHANGELOG.json
npm notice 469B CHANGELOG.md
npm notice 262B lib/MyProps.d.ts
npm notice 48B lib/MyProps.js
npm notice 427B lib/MyProps.js.map
npm notice 415B package.json
npm notice 197B rush-logs/my-project.build.log
npm notice 26B src/index.d.ts
npm notice 260B src/types/MyProps.tsx
npm notice 53B src/types/index.d.ts
npm notice 634B tsconfig.json
npm notice Tarball Details
npm notice name: @MYCOMPANY/my-project
npm notice version: 0.1.4
npm notice filename: MYCOMPANY-my-project-0.1.4.tgz
npm notice package size: 12.5 kB
npm notice unpacked size: 21.3 kB
npm notice shasum: 4e5fab8828a4d65afa96c5f7d60a6715c3d096ac
npm notice integrity: sha512-4lRGJpd4/XDqD[...]GSQh5yKflxrAw==
npm notice total files: 14
npm notice
npm error code ENEEDAUTH
npm error need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm error need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`

npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\BridgetteRyan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-07-19T06_32_07_313Z-debug-0.log

ERROR: Process exited with code 1

I have tested rush add with a package scoped to this, and can confirm my environment file is using the env variables, but publishing is failing using the :\_authToken=${AZURE_ARTIFACTS_CI_AUTH_TOKEN} added to the end as suggested in the rushjs documentation.
UPDATE:
So I have found the issue, when I checked the copied .npmrc file from the .npmrc-publish, I can see:

; MISSING ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE: //pkgs.dev.azure.com/OURCOMPANY/OURPROJECT/\_packaging/OURREPOSITORY/npm/registry/:\_authToken=${AZURE_ARTIFACTS_CI_AUTH_TOKEN}

Trying to find out how to fix this now.
